# Automatic Backup/Restore embedded orientdb database

Tags: orientdb

I am using orientDB in embedded mode via java api. How do i perform automatic backup/restore the database at certain interval of time ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you made any effort yourself? Some code would make it easier for you to get help!

Answer (score 1):

Just create a TimerTask that run every X milliseconds and execute a database.backup(). Example of backup that is executed every 10 minutes (600,000 milliseconds):

```
  new Timer(true).schedule( new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      database.backup();
    }
   }, 600000, 600000 );
```